# How to phrase a question about jRPG replacement (e.g game like Final Fantasy II) better?

Tags: discussion, question-quality

I'd like to ask a question about finding a game that would play like Final Fantasy II, just more modern (e.g. bigger screen) but with similar game principles/mechanics. I know what they are called (jRPGs), but I am unsure what level of detail would be appropriate to make it a good question. This is what I have so far. Is this good enough? If not, how should I edit it?

---

S:

An cheap RPG that has similar gameplay to Final Fantasy II.

---

B:

Looking for am RPG game that plays similar to Final Fantasy II (US SNES numbering... it was called [FFIV in Japan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Final_Fantasy_IV)).

Specific elements of gameplay required:

- Turn based system
- Zero realtime element outside ABS (see next bullet)
- Active Battle system (or similar) [[1]](http://finalfantasy.wikia.com/wiki/Battle_System#Active_Time_Battle), [[2]](http://www.giantbomb.com/active-time-battle/3015-95/),[[4]](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gameplay_of_Final_Fantasy#Parties_and_battles)
- Ability to move around parts of the world fast (airship, chocobo equivalent)
- Strong storyline
- Ability to escape any non-boss monster
- Hidden items, secret areas etc...
- Ability to pass the game without grinding for XP (FF2 had a speed-walkthrough proving that you could pass it pretty much by fighting only bosses in large part)
- A world bigger than FF2, with somewhat more modern graphics.
- Ideally, playable full-screen on Windows system
- Well documented (e.g. there are FAQs on various secrets, walk-throughs etc... available)
- Platform: Windows or Linux.
- Cost: Ideally, free as in beer, but anything up to $10 is OK. BUT no [freemium](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Freemium)!
- Don't care much about multiplayer options.

---

Comment: It starts to get rather specific too. I wouldn't downvote/flag this question, but I feel like having huge number of really specific requirements makes it hard to give any meaningful answers. Or the question reduces to "is there almost perfect clone for program X". But no, I don't have any suggestions to improve that. But the one thing you could do is to give priority-ordered list of requirements.

Comment: If there's suggestion where you're not able to escape any non-boss monster, or another that costs $20, which one is better? (Bad examples, and of course both answers should be posted, with appropriate comments)

Answer (score 1):

Yes: The question seems to be phrased good enough. You should post it.